# Is $\underset{y}{\sup} g(x,y)$ continuous in x?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

I got a bit confused about the following:

Suppose $g: X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous in $x$ and $y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are some metric spaces. I was assuming that then

$h : X \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$
$h(x) =  \underset{y} \sup g(x,y)$

is continuous. The idea I have in mind is the following:

Assume some open set $B$ in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. Take any $x$ in $h^{-1}(B)$.

If $h(x)$ is finite, we find some $y'$ where $g(x,y')$ is sufficiently close to $h(x)$ and then by continuity of $g$  some $x'$ in a neighborhood of $x$ such that again $g(x',y')$ is sufficiently close to $h(x)$.

On the other hand, if we would find for $x'$ some $y''$ such that $g(x',y'')$ is too big, we have that $g(x,y'')$ would also be too big.

For the infinite case, we argue similar to the first part of the preceding arguments (i.e. if $g(x,y)$ is unbounded, then for some neighboring $x$, $g$ should also be unbounded).

Am I misleaded here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the statment is true as written. For example take $X = Y = \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ under the standard topology and $$g(x,y) = \frac{xy}{xy + 1}$$ Then $h(0) = 0$ but for every $x > 0$, $h(x) = 1$.

However, the statment is true if we assume $Y$ is compact. Fix $x \in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Then for every $y \in Y$, let $U_y$ be an open rectangle containing $(x,y)$ satisfying $$\sup_{(a,b),(c,d) \in U_y} d(g(a,b), g(c,d)) < \epsilon $$. These sets form an open cover for $\{(x,y): y \in Y\}$ which is compact so there is a finite subcover $U_1, U_2, \cdots, U_n$. Since each was an open retangle, there exists a $\sigma > 0$ such that if $d(x',x) < \sigma$, then for every $y \in Y$, $$(x',y) \in \bigcup_{i = 1}^n U_i$$So if $d(x',x) < \sigma$, $$d(h(x'),h(x)) < \epsilon$$ so $h$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample, that cleared up some things. I think I was implicitly assuming uniform continuity or alike in the second half of my idea.